# What is a better vertical divider solution?

Tags: html, css

better way of making a vertical divider in a centre of 2 divs. I want the divider to be in middle the "why choose" and "gallery"

like my example[image]

This is what I've tried but if you have a better solution than this that'd be great. Giving 75px padding seems ok but I don't think its the best practice.

```
.why-choose-us{
    padding: 0  10px;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    ul li{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-left: -30px;
        line-height: 2;
        clear: both;
    }
}

.gallery{
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 75px;
    border-left: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    img{
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 5px
    }
}
```

So if divs are 400px each then few more px are still available for the divider, so let say   .

http://jsfiddle.net/21g2Lona/1/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/21g2Lona/1/

Comment: I didn;t see any difference though :/

Comment: Give a margin to the right container.

Comment: in the gallery tag? but its already padded though? or change the padding to margin?

Answer (score 0):

May be use CSS multicolumn layout?

```
-webkit-column-count: 2;
```

You would just need to place all the markup in one column, let the CSS create the separator for you.

PS: You would need to use appropriate vendor prefixes along with `-webkit`.

Comment: Err... I would agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am a huge fan of the CSS flexbox module for these kinds of layouts. You can read about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's currently supported by 86% of the browsers people use according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

To make it show up correctly in all browsers you can use [fallbacks and prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

However, your solution is also fine. I just would use margin instead of padding if you're doing it this way. And of course, using `float` for these kinds of major layouts can lead to many problems and could require lots of additional CSS rules to fix.

Comment: but when I use margin-left:75px; instead of padding it doesn't make any space between the images and the divider :/

Comment: Remove the `padding-left` from `.gallery` and add `margin-right` to `.why-choose-us`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of using [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp): border-box sizing whenever you need to divide a page vertically and include padding, margings, or borders.

The default `box-sizing` is `content-box` which will apply the `width` rule only to the content of the element--if borders, padding, or margin are added they will be in-addition to the width.  `border-box` changes this so the width rule applies to the entire element--if borders, padding, or margin are added they will not increase the element's size, but rather consume space within the element.

Here's an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/21g2Lona/5/

Here's the salient bits:

```
section {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery{
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
...
}
```

The `section` rule does pretty much everything but add the border.  The key bit is the combination of `box-sizing: border-box` and `width: 50%`.  Together they mean that each `<section>` will be 50% of the width of their parent element, and that their width includes their border, margin, and padding.  Regular `box-sizing` uses `content-box`, in which case the `width` rule applies only to the content--adding any padding, border, or margin will further widen the element's overall size on page.

Comment: Good approach I supposed but I was trying to do is to put the divider in middle of the divs *exactly in the middle*.

Comment: well, if you put a 1px border on the right-side of the first section, and a 1px border on the left-side of the second second then it'll be perfectly centered.

Comment: Sorry that confused me a little, could you post a jsfiddle instead if that's okay.